# Remove-Item throws File not found

Tags: powershell, powershell-2.0, powershell-3.0

I am new to power shell script. I need a Power shell script to Check the available disk space and delete some old subfolders from a folder until the free space reaches threshold level.

Within "D:\InstallApp\Backup" this path I have multiple folders each with date as folder name. I have to delete some of the old dated back up folder to let the free space reach the threshold level.Thanks in
Advance :)

```
$driveLetter = "D"
$directory = "D:\InstallApp\Backup"
$desiredGiB = 266

$desiredBytes = $desiredGiB * 1073741824
Get-PSDrive $driveLetter | ForEach-Object { $free = $_.Free }
$list = $(Get-ChildItem $directory -File | Sort-Object -Property LastWriteTime)

#Write-Output $list 

if ($free -lt $desiredBytes) {
    $toDelete = @()
    $needed = $desiredBytes - $free
    $spaceToFree = 0
    
    foreach ($item in $list) {
        $toDelete += $item
        #write-Output $toDelete 
        $spaceToFree += $item.Length
        #write-Output $spaceToFree 
        if ($spaceToFree -ge $needed) {
            break
        }
    }
    
    $toDelete | ForEach-Object {
        ## Remove -WhatIf when you are comfortable that this is working as intended
        Remove-Item $toDelete 
    }
}
```

All the steps works fine except the deleting step. Remove-Item throws file not found exception

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Remove-Item` expects strings for the `-Path` (check out `Remove-Item -?`), so the file items are converted to strings, which will be the file names only, not full paths.

Use

```
$toDelete | foreach { Remove-Item $_.FullName }
```

or better

```
$toDelete | Remove-Item
```

Comment: Thanks for your response.  tried $toDelete | Remove-Item . IT does not show any error at the same time files are also not getting deleted. Files are sill there and with his $toDelete | foreach { Remove-Item $_.FullName } it still showed the same error.

Comment: @SubasriKalyankumar Try the `-Verbose` switch, check if the paths are correct. Also check your code, make sure not to delete any files twice.

Comment: Thanks. Also I found that $list = $(Get-ChildItem $directory -File | Sort-Object -Property LastWriteTime) this line does not return anything. There is nothing saved in $list variable.

Comment: @SubasriKalyankumar You probably missed the `-Recurse` switch? `Get-ChildItem $directory -File -Recurse`

Comment: Hi Marsze, The files are getting deleted now.I have made modifications in my code. I am facing another issue now. It will be great if you could help me with that too. I have posted it as a separate question. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64574932/power-shell-script-to-delete-some-old-data-to-free-up-space-upto-certain-limit . My issue is all the folders are getting deleted. The variable from which I am calculating free space is not getting updated. Thank you Sooo Much for your timely help. :)